# Is this too much responsibilities for one class?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I got a command : MovePlayerCommand.

One of the validator for this command does 3 things :

- calculate the cost for the player to move (can be called for validation but also for displaying purpose)
- validate this cost
- listen to the "PlayerMoved" event so we can apply the costs (for instance - 10 action point).

Is this too much responsibilities for a single class ? If so how would you separate this ?

Edit : I know that removing the cost and checking it are 2 things, but I cant separate them from the computing of this costs, and I don't want to have 3 classes for each Action

Comment: Would this question be better on [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I guess game development is more about real time or game design, not DDD or SRP

Comment: What do you mean by validator? A command validator should be responsible for validating that the content of the command is correct. eg ensure all mandatory properties of the command have values. Validators shouldn't carry out domain logic...

Comment: Validator carries the domain logic of course ! Validator are here for saying "Can this operation be performed ?" http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/02/15/validation-in-a-ddd-world/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big misunderstanding here, as some poeple making comments seem to be mixing DDD and CQRS. The OP is talking about commands and has tagged the question with cqrs, so I am going to assume that the OP is indeed using DDD with CQRS.

The domain validation logic should be in the command handler, you can do, and indeed should do data checking before the command hits the handler stub, but not do any domain logic validation. That said, there is no other place where you could validate the command against the domain logic other than in the command handler because that is the place where your aggregates are loaded.

The validations you are showing are domain validations, so they should be actually performed by your aggregate, so yes, I think you should break that responsibility a bit, and split the different types of validation: data and domain.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to answer definitively without a lot more information.

That said, what you described does not sound like a validator; it sounds like a "calculator" of sorts.

It's likely that the calculating methods would belong in one class (the calculator class), and the validator class would then reference the calculator.

I tend to handle domain events in a very thin handler class, which then defers to an aggregate root or service (this is a common but not universal practice).  So the root or service would likely also have a reference to the calculator (and possibly the validator).

This question may be too broad for SO, and might be better answered on a DDD forum.  Even then, you may need to provide more background.